# Serializing structs as compactly as possible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I want to serialize and deserialize all kinds of structs for a multiplayer game. I'm currently using the json serialization from unity:

```
public static T GetObject<T>(byte[] bytes) {
        T t = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(encoding.GetString(bytes));
        return t;
    }

    public static byte[] GetBytes(object obj) {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(obj);
        return encoding.GetBytes(json);
    }
```

It's working very well but the problem is that json is obviously not that compact. I tried BinaryFormatter and Marshalling but BinaryFormatter creates a big header that I don't think I need and Marshalling doesn't work well with arrays and structs inside structs. I want the system to be as flexible as possible because new structs are added frequently.

The json serialization worked perfectly with arrays, structs inside structs and types like strings or vectors. So what I'm looking for is something like the json serializer but more compact.

Example structs:

```
struct A {
    Vector3 position;
    string name;
}
struct B {
    uint id;
    A[] examples;
}
```

Comment: What does the struct look like? can you add attributes? protobuf works quite nicely in many cases, and protobuf-net is usually easy to retrofit onto existing types by just adding some attributes; if you have an example of your struct(s), I can probably be more specific

Comment: Yes, I can add attributes and I will look into protobuf. I can give some example structs but I want to be able to add more structs over time.

Comment: (adding more over time) I understand that; I was just trying to a: gauge how applicable it would be, and b: help you get started

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Hi, two questions: 
- is there a reason why you need to use json
- how do you plan on transmitting between client and server

Im asking, because there are many options to make that better, 
like zipstreaming the json string which would be easy, to compressed replies from the webserver which would be no work at all, to BSON, or protobuf, 
I understand you do not want to use normal C# built in serialization, or would that be an option? etc.etc.

Comment: No, I currently use json because it works with any struct I give it but I'm looking for a more compact option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf-net may be an option; given the example in the question, this could be:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
struct A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Vector3 position;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string name;
}
[ProtoContract]
struct B
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public uint id;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public A[] examples;
}
```

with usage something like:

```cs
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Vector3 may be a nuicanse, as it doesn't fit any normal patterns; tweak it...
        // (only need to do this once somewhere early on in the program)
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Vector3), false)
            .Add(nameof(Vector3.x), nameof(Vector3.y), nameof(Vector3.z));

        // test object
        var original = new B {
            id = 42,
            examples = new [] {
                new A {
                    position = new Vector3(1, 2, 3),
                    name = "abc"
                }
            }
        };
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        // serialize
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, original);
        // show the hex (normally you wouldn't do this - you'd just use the binary
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length));
        // deserialize (remembering that MemoryStream needs to be rewound)
        ms.Position = 0;
        var b = Serializer.Deserialize<B>(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(b.id);
        var a = b.examples.Single();
        Console.WriteLine(a.name);
        Console.WriteLine(a.position.x);
        Console.WriteLine(a.position.y);
        Console.WriteLine(a.position.z);
    }
}
```

This gives me 26 bytes as opposed to 74 bytes of UTF-8 via `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` for the same payload.

You might want to try it both with and without the custom setup step for `Vector3`. A few additional note: if you're using AOT, you may have some problems with *any* tools that perform runtime metaprogramming, which protobuf-net does extensively. But it is relatively easy to set it up to test it in your environment, at least!